# 2 line bootstrap navbar with icon,

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really new to bootstrap and I'm trying to create the following navbar.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  75   |    inconveniently long brand name in 60 pixel row    |
| pixel |                                                      |
| icon  |             lots  of  menu  items  in  25  pixel  row|
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can display a shorter (initials) brand name using hidden/display when the screen is too narrow, and I'd like the hamburger for the second row menu items when necessary.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn from my example here. :)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">

    <div class="container topnav">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/origin.png" alt="MACDONALD" style="margin: auto 200px !important;">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand topnav"><img class="img-responsive" id="image-fix" src="img/origin.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="margin: auto 200px !important;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">Welcome</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Here the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/3ovoGZ5Lr8)

Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've just tried you solution but the left hand icon seems to be part of the second row whereas I was trying to get its height to match the total heights of both rows (plus a little padding)

Comment: can you screenshot what are you doing so far?